# TypeScript - Not respecting an undefined check in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am showing this IconButton element conditionally,

```
{value.content &&
   <IconButton aria-label="copy" onClick={() => copyContent(value.content)}>
     <ContentCopy />
   </IconButton>
}
```

However I keep getting the typescript warning `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` for parameter `value.content` in `copyContent(value.content)` . I thought `value.content` would make the check if its undefined, and if not, not show the element, and no need to worry about the onClick.

Any ideas what I am I missing here? I tried adding `value.content && value.content !== undefined`, but still get the error.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think the type of the variable `value.content` be set to `string | undefined` will fix the issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOx7pN) fit your need? Please let me know and I can write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You narrowed the type of something in a scope, and then created a function from that to be executed later. And the problem is that, because the function is executed later, you can't be certain that the narrowed you did still applies.

For example:

```
const value: { content: string | null } = { content: "abc" }

if (value.content) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(value.content.toUpperCase()) // type error
  }, 1000)
}

value.content = null
```

This code would crash at runtime. You check `value.content`, and all seems good. But after you check it the value gets cleared. Then one second later the function runs and `value.content.toUpperCase()` crashes because `value.content` is now `null`.

Maybe that object will change, maybe it won't. But the point is that the Typescript cannot *guarantee* that it will not change.

---

You could check it again.

```
const value: { content: string | null } = { content: "abc" }

if (value.content) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    value.content && console.log(value.content.toUpperCase()) // fine
  }, 1000)
}

value.content = null
```

Now you've protected yourself against a possible change from some other code.

---

But what I recommend is to reference `content` as a local `const` which can't be reassigned because it's a `const`.

```
const value: { content: string | null } = { content: "abc" }

const content = value.content
if (content) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(content.toUpperCase()) // fine
  }, 1000)
}

value.content = null // does not change the value in `const content`
```

And now a change to the `value` object doesn't matter, because you've pulled the `content` from it, and if it's changed later then it won't affect this function at all.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gDcUAbAVyQC44BvOSqmJP050owKgHM4AHzhUWTJnAC+cALzde1AULgAiFACM0u5eT51N-QfHWNWSAHR9tMUsExwAFM+sBKbqRwcDRIMAAqoEgQLDCenv6qAHwBQUHmEEyOTBDi3lrWDjAQAKpgYEhQAMIoIfH+APT1cJhiSIHKADRwAIwADP2+pErkdmxO+fxqsvKKjXAAJhBINLIQ8GgAFigSSHAwG7uju2JwAAbm6xMwp3BAA)

---

Or more specific to your case, something like:

```
function MyComp({ value }: { value: { content: string | null } }) {
  const content = value.content

  return <>{content &&
    <div onClick={() => copyContent(content)}>
      clickMe
    </div>
  }</>
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrjQjAE8BhBmJamACma8eMAFxwAzjCjBqAcwCUcAN6k4cAPTqAdDtIBfclVox6jALIdcYPkrgA3FABtKSOHrG2HzpB6ZdhYpLScnAAPnDUlI6Obm6KKmqCkn5CvHAAvPZOLlqC3LzkakQwlFCMADwAfEp5wnAAZPWqanDlACbAdnAM7I7AaADW6Up8iumVfmycqfy1vPJ6lc0tTH2DZkjLreoddktqeuXqSwZAA)

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Better understood now.